# Hibernate validator error messages file name

Tags: jakarta-ee, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

Can the ValidationMessages.properties file name changed to a different file name while using hibernate validator in JSF 2.0?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't give it a different name. But it's in theory possible to read from an arbitrary resource bundle yourself with a custom [`MessageInterpolator`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/validation/MessageInterpolator.html).

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate Validator defines the notion of [resource bundle locators](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/api/index.html?org/hibernate/validator/resourceloading/package-summary.html) which allow to customize the way how resource bundles are retrieved, while still using the standard message interpolation algorithm.

To retrieve messages from a custom resource bundle just define a `PlatformResourceBundleLocator` with the bundle name and create a `ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator` using the locator like this:

```
Validator validator =
    Validation.byProvider(HibernateValidator.class)
        .configure()
        .messageInterpolator(
            new ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator(
                new PlatformResourceBundleLocator( "my_bundle" )))
        .buildValidatorFactory()
        .getValidator();
```